# Launch activity with custom permission through adb

Tags: android, adb, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-build

I am trying to launch an activity using `adb`. If I remove the custom permission tag `android:permission` from below snippet from manifest (manifest stripped for brevity), then everything is working fine.

```
<manifest ... package="com.example.pkgname">
    <permission android:name="com.example.pkgname.BIND" 
       android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
       .
       .
       .
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.pkgname.BIND" />
    <application android:allowBackup="false" 
         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
         android:label="@string/app_name" 
         android:name="com.example.pkgname.ManagerApplication" 
         android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/Theme.Security.Main">
        <activity 
           android:exported="true" 
           android:launchMode="singleTask" 
           android:name="com.example.activity1" 
           android:permission="com.example.pkgname.BIND" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I tried this : `adb shell am start -n com.example.pkgname/com.example.activity1` 
which threw below error :

> Security exception: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.pkgname/com.example.activity1 } from null (pid=16893, uid=3000) requires com.example.pkgname.BIND

How do I launch activity with custom permissions through adb?

Comment: can't defined custom permission in android manifest file.

Comment: did you try starting the activity with your user permission?

Comment: @Debdeep - That's what I want to do but not sure how to do it using adb. There seems no such parameter in adb manual.

Comment: `adb shell dumpsys package com.package.app | grep userId=` will give you the respective id

Comment: Use it: `adb shell am start  
-n com.package.app/.HomeActivity
--user XXXXX`